# Alternate access mappings have not been configured

Tags: 2013

My old DNS was DNSOld for sharepoint server. So I changed Alternate access mappings as DNSOld for Intranet.

I changed DNS again as DNSNew. I changed Alternate access mappings too. But the logs are like this:

> Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site `http://sharepoint_server` with the URL `http://DNSOld`.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL `http://DNSOld` as an AAM response URL.
>   Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri `http://DNSOld/_layouts/15/core.debug.js?rev=HMlx90NziE60dQZ6I9yj2Q==`.

And every 1 or 2 am I've got this error:

> The DataSourceID of 'V4QuickLaunchMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource. A control with ID 'QuickLaunchSiteMap' could not be found

How can I solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused over this question. Did you start by changing the zone **default** to **intranet**, and then tried to add a new default zone, or did you leave the default zone unchanged?

Comment: I select "Add Internal URLs" and enter the DNSNew Url. In edit public url the default is sharepoint server url and intranet is DNSNew url. I didn't change public url

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Central Administration, go to Application Management and then in the section Web Applications, go to Configure alternative access mappings, or use the following URL `http://CentralAdminURL/_admin/AlternateUrlCollections.aspx`.

In the selector **Alternative Access Mapping Collection:** select the Web Application you want to extend, by clicking Show All.

[image]

Next, select Edit Public URLs

[image]

... where you can add your `DNSNew` :s URL to the intranet zone of your Web Application:

[image]

## Edit

> In addition to the actual Alternate Access Mapping in SharePoint Central Administration, you also have to add a Binding in IIS, contrary to what many believe, except for the initial hostheader when you create the web application, SharePoint does not do that for you, so you have to do it manually.
> The example above would show up in IIS Bindings like this:

[image]

Reference: [A guide to Alternate Access Mappings Basics in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I wrote in my question that I do it. But it didn't work.

Comment: @e.ozmen But in your comment above, you wrote that you hit the link "Add Internal URLs" and not "Edit public URLs", which is what I'm trying to show. Did you follow these mentioned steps and still it didn't work?

Comment: When I add the internal link, it appears in edit public zone urls intranet zone automaticaly.

Comment: @e.ozmen ...and if you select just your *Alternative Access Mapping Collection* to the right in image 2, do you see both default zone and intranet zone?

Comment: Yes I see them.

Comment: @e.ozmen Good! Have you set up the bindings in IIS? (If not, see my edited answer).

Comment: Ok I forgot it. I changed the settings. But I can only say tomorrow that it works. But for now the error logs disappeared. :)