# Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri - Error

Tags: 2013, error, sharepoint-server, uls

I am getting the following error numerous times in the ULS on both our SP 2013 web front ends:

```
Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://<server IP address>/

Process: w3wp.exe

Name: Request (GET:http://<server IP address>/)
```

We are using VMware and a virtual IP address maps both WFE's to the same IP) for our DNS.

Anyone know why this error is occurring? Can't find much info on the web.

Thanks.

Comment: Please visit below URL. I hope your issue has been resolved by this. [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/alternate-access-mappings-have-not-been-configured](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/alternate-access-mappings-have-not-been-configured)

Comment: All credit to Jay Doshi's link.

I was running into the same issue.

My issue was not that it was not configured, but it was configured incorrectly.

I leftt 443 in the url when the web application was created (e.g. https:\\www.site.com:443).  The AAM reflected this as well.  When I removed 443 from the AAM so it matched our DNS record I was able to access site.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reason that this error occurs is that the alternate access mapping is not configured accurately. If there is something wrong with the alternative access mapping, then this type of message can occur stating that they cannot find site lookup info for request Uri.

To manage the alternate access mappings, you need to click system settings on the SharePoint central administration. Then go to the farm management section and click on configure intermittent access mappings.

Sometimes this error message also occurs if your website is an HTTP website but you trying to search it as an https website.