# SharePoint 2013 - ULS logs Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

One of our WFE was running at 100% CPU. Rebooted it through VM console as I could not login. Some users are getting pointed to the home page, but both WFE are now spamming ULS logs with: Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri //SERVERNAME

Both WFE servers are getting this error. Some users are hitting a blank site, some hitting the correct site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set AAM for your farm? One of the possible reasons is that the AAM is not correctly configured. You may need to check it. As you mention "Some users are hitting a blank site, some hitting the correct site." Do they use the same url?

[Alternate access mappings have not been configured](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/alternate-access-mappings-have-not-been-configured)

[Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri - Error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94044/cannot-find-site-lookup-info-for-request-uri-error)