# SP sites unreachable due to AAM misconfiguration

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping

Somehow our whole AAM configuration has gone down the crapper over night and I am scratching my head on how to restore it.

Thoe only configuration present (for the web application at :80) at the moment is

```
Internal URL               |   Zone Public   |   URL for Zone 
http://portal.domain.com       Default           http://portal.domain.com
```

Where `portal.domain.com` is the actual public address of the machine. No internal urls are present at the moment and the sites are not reachable except for the Central administration, which is reachable locally.

If I visit a sitecollection on this webcollection on Chrome I get a blank page.
If I visit the same address on IE11 I get an http response code 403 forbidden ( but no login prompt)

I've followed [Alternate access mappings have not been configured](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/alternate-access-mappings-have-not-been-configured)

but to no avail. Please help me out on this one.

Comment: Are the bindings still intact in the IIS on the WFE server(s)?

Comment: Yes. the http binding for port 80 and the domain `portal.domain.com` for all IP addresses unassigned is still active in IIS

Comment: I found the one of the reasons why it was not working. As it turns out, "Require SSL" was enabled, although SSL is optional for this domain AND the SSL AAM is missing. So there were to errors playing hand in hand.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I've written in the comments to my question, one of the errors was "Require SSL" was enabled in the IIS configuration for this web site.

I don't know how the AAM could have gone missing, but I've recreated the SSL AAM. After this I went through restarting the SharePoint Timer service, SharePoint Administration service and restarting IIS and it worked again.